# What is the object instantiated from an Interface

Tags: java, interface

There is an interface like this:

```
public interface Person {
    public String getName();
}
```

and then there is a class `Student` which implements `Person`:

```
public class Student implements Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

What would an instance of `Person` look like at runtime? How do I instantiate?

Comment: What are you asking? There is no way to instantiate `Person` directly, only classes that implement `Person`. So, `new Student()` would instantiate a `Student` instance. The `Student` will implement the `Person` interface.

Comment: `interface` is a lot like an `abstract class` in that you can't directly instantiate an instance.

Comment: It will be dark hair, blue-eye, and tall...

Comment: @apomene, thanks. You've got a good taste. Now move on to the next level of trolling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't instantiate an interface.

What you can do is instantiate an **implementation** of an interface - in your case, `Student`.

```
Person s = new Student();
```

In this case, `s` will implement Person and you can check it with:

```
boolean isPerson = (s instanceof Person);
```

which will be evaluated to `true`

Comment: Did you mean `Person p = new Student();`?

Comment: There is. The `Person` interface provides an **abstraction**, which is implemented by `Student`. So, there **IS** a `Person` object, which has special properties.

Comment: `Person` is an interface. Think about the word `interface` for a second. When you say something is an *interface*, that means it describes how you interact with something else. So an `interface` describes how you will interact with an object instance that implements it.

Comment: I've seen something like this to implement DTOs. Actually the interface is called `somethingDTO` including some `getters` and then there is an `Entity` which implements those getters. Is this insane?

Comment: @MikaelS. I don't suggest putting getters/setters on an interface. If you need getters/setters then you should be making an `abstract class` instead of an `interface`. That's my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate Person it is interface

you can only instantiate Student like

```
    Person p1= new Student();

             or 
   Student S1 = new Student();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can never instantiate an `interface` in java. You can, however, refer to an object that implements an interface by the type of the interface. For example,

```
 Person test = new Student();
```

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in other answers, `Person` is an interface so can't be instantiated. Therefore it is useful to include the arguments in the constructor of the implementing class since the latter's setters will not be directly accessible from a `Person` reference

```
public Student(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

so as to initialize

```
Person s = new Student(1, "Jon Smith");
```